# Initialising inherited structure with initialiser list

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying the following:

```
struct A
{
    int x;
};

struct B: A
{
    int y;
};

B foo = {1, 2};
```

But I get:

```
error: could not convert '{1, 2}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'B'
```

This is using C++11.  Can I get round it without defining an explicit constructor?

Comment: You don't need the public, by the way. Access is public by default for structs.

Comment: no. Having said that I seem to remember seeing a proposal somewhere that would allow it in a future version of c++.

Comment: @Richard Hodges the duplicate marked has a link to the proposal just fyi.

Comment: @SamerTufail many thanks, although I wouldn't use it even if I could - so brittle!.

Comment: @Richard Hodges agreed. I would prefer an explicit ctor.